# How do I limit the size (in pixels) of characters to be recognized by PyTesseract?

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to use `PyTesseract` for recognizing text from some scanned documents, which contain simple text as well as complicated diagrams.

`PyTesseract` misinterprets the diagrams (or parts of it) as characters, which I do not want to happen. A solution to this problem would be to limit the maximum size (`width`, or `height`) of characters to be recognized, and ignore the rest of the larger characters (i.e.-the diagrams)

Is there any way I can limit the maximum size of characters to be recognized?

`PyTesseract version - LooseVersion ('5.0.0-alpha.20200328'); Python 3.8.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a trivial solution to this problem, so I am posting it here.
I used pytesseract.image_to_boxes

```
    data = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img)

    boxes = re.split(' ', data)

    line = list()
    coords = list()
    letters = [boxes[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(boxes)):
        if (i%5 != 0):
            line.append(int(boxes[i]))
        else:
            letters.append(boxes[i][2:])
            coords.append(line)
            line = []

    for i in range(0, len(coords)):
        print(letters[i], coords[i])
```

The above code segregates the letters and the coordinates into two respective lists.
After this I used the condition

```
    if (abs(coords[i][2] - coords[i][0]) < size) and (abs(coords[i][3] - coords[i][1]) < size+5):
```

to filter out the required characters

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'size' variable is supposed to be in this example, could you elaborate?

Comment: Hey @dbaser, sorry for the ambiguity. The `size` attribute here was analogous to the text size in Word Processors. Numerically it would mean the height of the characters.